# h:commandButton not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm having a problem with JSF `CommandButton` action not working. I have a managed bean `merchantController` and I'm using following code in controller to display `popUpURL` page.

```
RequestContext
                .getCurrentInstance()
                .execute(
                        "document.getElementById('viewForm:actionHref').href='"
                                + popUpURL
                                + "';document.getElementById('viewForm:actionHref').click();");
```

I am getting `popUpURL` at code while debugging.but it doesn't works.

Now I'm using jsf code for button as follows

```
<div class="table-footer">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h:outputLabel value=" " styleClass="control-label" />

                            <div class="mBtm10 mTop20" >
                                <h:commandButton id="modifyBtn" value="MODIFY" styleClass="btn01 btn actionBtn" 
                                     update=":msg"
                                    disabled="#{merchantController.status eq 'B' ? 'true' : merchantController.status eq 'I' ? 'true' : merchantController.merchantDataModel.getRowCount() eq 0 ? 'true' : 'false'}"
                                    actionListener="#{merchantController.manipulateUsers('Modify')}" />
                                <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h:outputLink value="#1" id="actionHref" style="display:none;"
                        styleClass="link02 group1" />
```

But When I use `p:commandbutton` instead of `h:commandbutton` ,it works fine. What should be the problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear ? Are you trying to open modal popup of PF on button click ?

Comment: Debug the network traffic and content and pay attention to the differences... Then read about the basic fundamental differences between a normal `h:commandButton` and a `p:commandButton`

Comment: Thanks.......................................................................